# collecting user keyevent input for 2 secs and then clear it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have

```
private userInputTimer;
private userInputText = '';

private handleEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
 if((keyNum >= 48 && keyNum <= 90) || (keyNum >= 96 && keyNum <= 105)){  
      this.userInputText = (this.userInputText) ? this.userInputText : '';
      this.userInputText = this.userInputText + keyCode;
      clearTimeout(this.userInputTimer);
      this.setUserInputClearTimer();
  }

setUserInputClearTimer(){
 this.userInputTimer = setTimeout(() => {
  this.userInputText = '';
  }, 500);
}
```

Using this code, I can delete the text which the user has entered consecutively  after 500 ms.

How can I achieve this behavior using RxJs debounce. I would really appreciate some help

Comment: Share your html code as well.

Comment: @SunilSingh Nothing much to show, just `(keydown)=handleEvent($event)`. I want to monitor this event on my own custom component so that i can take some actions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with reactive form input control valuechanges().

**Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGrp">
<input type="text" formControlName="userInputText" name="username"/>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
this.formGrp.get('userInputText').valueChanges().pipe(
  debouneTime(2000),
  map((_enteredText)=>{
    const enteredText = _enteredText;
    this.formGrp.get('userInputText').setValue('');
    return enteredText;
  })
).subscribe(value=> console.log(value));
```

Comment: No no, i dont want form. I want to monitor this event on my own custom component so that i can take some actions accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use -

1. `fromEvent` which will capture the event of targeted element. debounceTime
2. `debounceTime` to delay the events

Here is the snippet

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.targetElement, 'keyup') //<-- put the event you want to capture
      // get value
      .map((evt: any) => evt.target.value) //<-- you can ignore this if you don't want the value from the control
      .debounceTime(2000)
      .subscribe((text: string) => {
           this.setUserInputClearTimer();
       });
```

Here is example you can refer to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-observable-form-input-debounce-kebtnt